# Django, how to pass just the last segment of url to view

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I'm attempting to pass a string from the end of a url to a view function, but I'm getting the entire url passed to `render_form()` i.e. if I input "myurl.me/prepend/identifier" I get "prepend/identifier/" when I just want "identifier"

These are my urls.py files, the top one is located in an app directory, the bottom one is in the project dir:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<identifier>.+)$', views.render_form),
)
```

--

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^prepend/', include('the_ones_above.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

I think it might have somehting to do with the split over 2 urlpatterns in 2 separate files, any ideas what im doing wrong?

Thanks!

edit: the view looks like: `def render_form(request, identifier=None):`
oh, and this is the latest django (from git)
2nd edit: removed the rather superfluous 1st url, behavior is still the same

Comment: What does `render_form` look like? Does it have `render_form(request, identifier)`?

Comment: def render_form(request, identifier=None):

Comment: And when you say I get `"prepend/identifier"` do you get it from `print identifier`? Or are you printing something else?

Comment: thats correct, identifier == "prepend/identifier/" thanks :)

Comment: Are there other urlpatterns that could interfere with these?

Comment: none, I actually removed an unnecessary one above that sould have been interfering I suppose, but the behavior is still the same

Comment: Did you modify the code for this question or is the code in the question the exact code that has the issue? Everyone looks okay to me so I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: i modified, the_ones_above.urls to make the question clearer, other thatn that, its as is.

Comment: Seems okey to me too. There is another problem...

Comment: hmm ok, interesting... i will investigate more. Thanks for your help

Comment: One recommendation: be more specific I  the url pattern match  `[\w]+`

Comment: ok, if I do this I get a not found message <code>url(r'^(?P<identifier>[\w]+)$', views.render_form), </code>

Comment: `url(r'^(?P<identifier>[\w]+)/$', views.render_form),` you've forgotten the `/` before `$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you to simply write you url like.

`url(r'^(?P<identifier>[\w]+)/$', views.render_form),`

[\w] will tell you that you can pass word character (A-Za-z0-9_).